# Finding adjoint of a Linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be two operators acting on a Hilbert space $H$. Define $\tau:H\to H\oplus H$ by
$$\tau(h)=(Ah,Bh).$$
How to find the adjoint of $\tau$? The inner product in $H\oplus H$ is defined in the usual way, i.e., for any $(x,y), (z,w)\in H\oplus H$,

$$\langle (x,y), (z,w) \rangle_{H\oplus H}= \langle x,z \rangle_H+\langle y,w \rangle_H.$$

I do not know, if this question is trivial. However, a detailed answer will be appreciated.

Comment: This question isn't trivial, but it's not difficult either. This seems like a perfect exercise to do for yourself. Start with the inner product $\langle \tau(h), (x, y) \rangle_{H \times H}$, and see what you can do with it. See if you can turn it into an expression of the form $\langle h, \underline{\hspace{3mm}}\rangle_H$, where the missing expression depends on $A$ and $B$ (and their conjugates), as well as $x$ and $y$. That expression is $\tau^*(x, y)$.

Comment: Thank you @TheoBendit. I shall try and update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjoint $\tau^{\ast}:H\otimes H\to H$ is the unique operator such that $(\tau(h),z+z')=(h,\tau^{\ast}(z+z))$. The left hand side of the equation yields $(Ah,z)+(Bh,z)=(h,A^{\ast}z)+(h,B^{\ast}z')=(h,A^{\ast}z+B^{\ast}z')$. By unicity of the adjoint, the adjoint $\tau^{\ast}:H\otimes H\to H$ is given by $\tau^{\ast}(z,z)=A^{\ast}z+B^{\ast}z'$

Comment: Thankyou @sein. I reached at the same answer. However, I believe it is a typo "\tau^*(z,z')"

Comment: Ah yeah of course, awsome that you found the result yourself only saw the comment of Theo after I posted the answer.